# C: How to reset the reurn value of clock() to 0?

Tags: c, time.h

I'd like to know if there is a way to reset the return value of the clock() function to 0.
I have a code something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    /* clock_t t1; */
    unsigned int sec = 0;
    while(true) {
        if(clock() >= 1000) {
            printf("%u seconds has passed\r", sec);
            /* reset clock()'s return value to 0 */
            sec++;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

what code should I put to the comment's place to reset the timer? Is there a way, or am I aproaching the problem in the incorrect manner?

Comment: Why would you want to mess with `clock` return value? If you want to do something in certain intervals, just store the result from `clock` when you execute the task. and compare with that value until the difference is large enough.

Comment: Is there any reason why you’re not just using a local variable to indicate whether another 1000ms has passed?

Comment: `%u seconds` clock is not in seconds.

Comment: From [the POSIX reference](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock.html): "*In order to measure the time spent in a program, `clock()` should be called at the start of the program and its return value subtracted from the value returned by subsequent calls.*" The [C11 Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.27.2.1) has a similar indication: "*319) In order to measure the time spent in a program, the clock function should be called at the start of the program and its return value subtracted from the value returned by subsequent calls.*".

Comment: @KamilCuk you're right should be CLOCKS_PER_SECOND instead of 1000.

Comment: the reason I wanted to reset clockk() instead of storing it, then comparing is because oif this code runs for long enougth, the clock() return value might get too big, and overflow. But thank you all for helping :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clock()` is always increasing.

The unit of clock is in `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`. One second has `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` clocks.

Note that `clock()` does not measure real time. `clock()` measures the processor time spend in your process. If you want to measure real time, use `time()` from `time.h` (or check your OS, on linux you can use `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, ...)` or with `CLOCK_REALTIME`).

Save the current clock in a variable. Then compare the variable with current clock.

Usually `stdout` is line buffered. So until you write a newline character, nothing will show up. Make sure to flush `stdout` if you depend on that behavior.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main() {
    unsigned int sec = 0;
    // we will stop the clock one second from now
    clock_t stopclock = clock() + 1 * CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    while(1) {
        // current time is greater then the stopping time
        if (clock() > stopclock) {
            // increment stopping time by one second
            stopclock += 1 * CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
            printf("\r%u seconds has passed", sec);
            fflush(stdout);
            sec++;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note: calculations on `clock_t` type like `clock() + 1 * CLOCKS_PER_SEC` can potentially overflow - great code would handle such corner cases.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you are trying to time something
Take a look at [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_clock.htm)

```c
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
   clock_t start_t, end_t, total_t;
   int i;

   start_t = clock();
   printf("Starting of the program, start_t = %ld\n", start_t);
    
   printf("Going to scan a big loop, start_t = %ld\n", start_t);
   for(i=0; i< 1000000000; i++) {
   }
   end_t = clock();
   printf("End of the big loop, end_t = %ld\n", end_t);
   
   total_t = (double)(end_t - start_t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
   printf("Total time taken by CPU: %f\n", total_t  );
   printf("Exiting of the program...\n");

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: Don't use the `_t` suffix for variables, it's not only confusing (you can see that markdown is formatting these variables as if they were types in your answer), but it's also [reserved in POSIX](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html).